# AWS SSO configuration via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, single-sign-on

I'm trying to figure out how to configure a AWS SSO to work with Gsuit following this guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-g-suite-as-external-identity-provider-aws-sso/

I've managed to configure everything manually and it works exactly as described in the guide, however I'm unable to find any terraform resources fitting for steps **3**,**4** and **5** from the guide under section "AWS SSO initial setup"

Has anyone bumped into this problem and how did you managed to terraform it?

Thanks

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_openid_connect_provider

Comment: Thanks Jordan, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. I would like to configure a SAML external provider under the AWS Single Sign On service not under IAM. What you are suggesting, as far as I understand it, works the other way around, where you as a user will open a 3th party SSO page and log in thorugh it, however my use case is to leverage the native AWS SSO and only pull identities from gsuit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: updated the main question

Answer (score 0):

The SSO APIs are very limited. You can see the available ones here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html

Unfortunately terraform needs those APIs to create the aws resources. Hopefully one day AWS will support more APIs for SSO.